# View option picked from datalist

Tags: javascript

I would like to take the option of which the user selects from a datalist. This is what I have:

```
<input type="text" name="my-input" class="searchBar" list="my-list">          
  <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="handleSelect();" />
  <datalist id="my-list">
        <option value="COMP232"></option>
        <option value="COMP248"></option>
        <option value="ENGR201"></option>
  </datalist>
```

My JS method:

```
function handleSelect()
        {
            var elm = document.getElementById("my-list").innerHTML.value;
            console.log(elm);
            //window.location = "./class/" + elm.toUpperCase() + ".php";
        }
```

The console responds "undefined" when I submit. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an `id` to input and take a value of `id` on button click.

```
<input id= "inp" type="text" name="my-input" class="searchBar" list="my-list">          
<input type="button" value="clickme" onclick="handleSelect();" />
                      <datalist id="my-list">
                            <option value="COMP232"></option>
                            <option value="COMP248"></option>
                            <option value="ENGR201"></option>
                      </datalist>
```

and JS code snippet will look like,

```
var elm = document.getElementById("inp").value;
```

Comment: Hi, when I add this command, it works on localhost but not online, why? `window.location = "./class/" + elm.toUpperCase() + ".php";`

Answer (score -1):

Your code should be like this.

```
<script>
function handleSelect(){
    var elment = document.getElementById("selectedValue").value;
    console.log(elment);    
}

</script>
<input id="selectedValue" type="text" name="my-input" class="searchBar" list="my-list">
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme"
    onclick="handleSelect();" />
<datalist id="my-list">
    <option value="COMP232"></option>
    <option value="COMP248"></option>
    <option value="ENGR201"></option>
</datalist>
```